# Google Blogger XML Layout Error For Designing Theme

Tags: xml, blogger, xml-layout

I want to divide the **Header area** into two parts **(No - Logo & No - Ad Area)** using **Google Blogger XML Layout**.

When I trying to save my XML codes the Blogger HTML Editor is showing an error --

> **The widget with id logo is not within a section (actual parent element**
>   **is: header.) Every widget should be in a section**.

Check My XML codes and also check attached image to understand more **What I Want ?**

```
<b:section class='header' id='header' maxwidgets='2' showaddelement='yes'>
<div class='container border-1'>
    <header class='row'>
        <b:widget id='logo' locked='true' title='' type='Header'>
            <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-1 border-1 d-none d-sm-block'> <div id='logo_main_area_device-lg__md__sm' style='background: #fff; max-height:90px !important; height:90px;'> <div id='logo-text_device-lg__md__sm'><a style='text-decoration:none !important; color:#000 !important;' href='//www.jobluto.com'>JobLuto.Com</a></div> </div> </div>
            <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-1 border-1 d-block d-sm-none'> <div id='logo_main_area_device-xs' style='background: #fff; max-height:50px !important; height:90px;'> <div id='logo-text_device-xs'><a style='text-decoration:none !important; color:#000 !important;' href='//www.jobluto.com'>JobLuto.Com</a></div> </div> </div>
        </b:widget>
        <b:widget id='ads1' locked='true' title='' type='Header'>
            <div class='col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-11 overflow-none border-1' style='background: #777; padding: 0 0.00000001px 0 0.00000001px;'> <img class='img-fluid' style='width:100% !important; height: 90px !important;' src='http://www.creditlenders.info/wp-content/uploads/banner-ad-banner-ads-macallister-design.jpg' alt=''/> </div>
        </b:widget>
    </header>
</div></b:section>
```

[Watch This Image To Understand My Requirment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwGW4.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Please help me to fix the ERROR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blogger, `b:section` tag can only contain widgets represented by `b:widget` tag. also, to insert your HTML code inside widgets use `b:include` tag like the following

```
<b:widget id='logo'>
  <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
     Your HTML code here
  </b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

Your code should be (*note class name row within section*)

```
<div class='container border-1'>
    <b:section class='header row' id='header' maxwidgets='2' showaddelement='yes'>
        <b:widget id='logo' locked='true' title='' type='Header'>
            <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
                <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-1 border-1 d-none d-sm-block'> <div id='logo_main_area_device-lg__md__sm' style='background: #fff; max-height:90px !important; height:90px;'> <div id='logo-text_device-lg__md__sm'><a style='text-decoration:none !important; color:#000 !important;' href='//www.jobluto.com'>JobLuto.Com</a></div> </div> </div>
                    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-1 border-1 d-block d-sm-none'> <div id='logo_main_area_device-xs' style='background: #fff; max-height:50px !important; height:90px;'> <div id='logo-text_device-xs'><a style='text-decoration:none !important; color:#000 !important;' href='//www.jobluto.com'>JobLuto.Com</a></div> </div> </div>
            </b:includable>
        </b:widget>
        <b:widget id='ads1' locked='true' title='' type='Header'>
          <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
            <div class='col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-11 overflow-none border-1' style='background: #777; padding: 0 0.00000001px 0 0.00000001px;'> <img class='img-fluid' style='width:100% !important; height: 90px !important;' src='http://www.creditlenders.info/wp-content/uploads/banner-ad-banner-ads-macallister-design.jpg' alt=''/> </div>
          </b:includable>
        </b:widget>
    </b:section>
</div>
```

Comment: It's showing error **The widget with id "logo" cannot contain element: "div". A widget can only contain b:includable elements**

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: Tell me please if I will repalce the value of the **id** of **<b:include>** then will it work ? Example: **<b:includable id='logo-data' var='this'> .... </b:include>**

Comment: `b:includable` doesn't appear in the final HTML doc, It's a Blogger widget tag and each widget must have one includable with id='main'

Comment: Tell me please **What is `maxwidgets` and How do I use it ?** and also tell me about **`var`**

Comment: `maxwidgets` attribute determines the maximum number of widgets that can be used in section.